# Setting media playback info in MacOs not working

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm a newbie in ObjC and MacOs development.
My final goal is understand how setting playback info works from ObjC to try to implement that later on Rust (using generated ObjC runtime bindings).

So right now I'm trying to write small piece of code on ObjC that would set playback info (without actually playing anything).
I have found https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-media-service/blob/master/src/darwin/service.mm and used it as a base.

Here's code I have right now:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#include "MediaPlayer/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.h"
#include "MediaPlayer/MPRemoteCommandCenter.h"
#include "MediaPlayer/MPRemoteCommand.h"
#include "MediaPlayer/MPMediaItem.h"
#include "MediaPlayer/MPRemoteCommandEvent.h"


@interface NativeMediaController : NSObject { }
@end

@implementation NativeMediaController
- (MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus)remotePlay {
    NSLog(@"Play");
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
  }
- (MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus)remotePause {
    NSLog(@"Pause");
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
  }
- (MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus)remoteTogglePlayPause {
    NSLog(@"PlayPause");
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
  }
- (MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus)remoteNext {
    NSLog(@"Next");
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
  }
- (MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus)remotePrev {
    NSLog(@"Previous");
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
  }

- (MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus)remoteChangePlaybackPosition:(MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"ChangePlaybackPosition");
  return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}

- (MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus)move:(MPChangePlaybackPositionCommandEvent*)event {
    NSLog(@"Move");
  return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
        NativeMediaController* controller = [[NativeMediaController alloc] init];

        MPRemoteCommandCenter *remoteCommandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
        [remoteCommandCenter playCommand].enabled = true;
        [remoteCommandCenter pauseCommand].enabled = true;
        [remoteCommandCenter togglePlayPauseCommand].enabled = true;
        [remoteCommandCenter changePlaybackPositionCommand].enabled = true;
        [remoteCommandCenter nextTrackCommand].enabled = true;
        [remoteCommandCenter previousTrackCommand].enabled = true;

        [[remoteCommandCenter playCommand] addTarget:controller action:@selector(remotePlay)];
        [[remoteCommandCenter pauseCommand] addTarget:controller action:@selector(remotePause)];
        [[remoteCommandCenter togglePlayPauseCommand] addTarget:controller action:@selector(remoteTogglePlayPause)];
        [[remoteCommandCenter changePlaybackPositionCommand] addTarget:controller action:@selector(remoteChangePlaybackPosition:)];
        [[remoteCommandCenter nextTrackCommand] addTarget:controller action:@selector(remoteNext)];
        [[remoteCommandCenter previousTrackCommand] addTarget:controller action:@selector(remotePrev)];
        
        NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [songInfo setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Test title"] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        [songInfo setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Test artist"] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
        [songInfo setObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:"Test albumtitle"] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle];
        [songInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:60.0] forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime];
        [songInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:360.0] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];
        [songInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:112233] forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID];
        
        [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].playbackState = MPNowPlayingPlaybackStatePlaying;
        [[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:songInfo];
        NSLog(@"End!");
        
        char input[50] = {0};
        printf("Enter anything to quit: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When this code is executed I see no effect in MacOs playing info widget.
Unfortunately right now I have no idea how to debug this or where can I find better ObjC example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason that caused my problem playing with Apple Swift example.
There're two requirements to show playback widget (i didn't find them documented anywhere) that have been missing:

- You should register a callback for at least one action (play, pause)
- You should build your application as an App, not as Console. If your program is not shown in the dock as a running app - the playback widget wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm trying to find a replacement for the `electron-media-service` module, one that works with code 13.2 (the one used by Github runners). Any ideas?

Comment: @Felipe Unfortunately, I don't know.

I know that NovusTheory started xosms project (https://github.com/NovusTheory/xosms) some time ago to create new elctron library for integration with media system on 3 OS (Win, Linux, MacOS).

I even made an PR (I'm pretty bad at Rust so my code is ugly and not production ready) to add MacOS support https://github.com/NovusTheory/xosms/pull/11

But I don't know if it works with Electron 13.2 . I also should say that this project not activeyly maintained now and should be considered as PoC.

Comment: @Felipe jFYI https://github.com/NovusTheory/xosms have just released 0.3.0 version with merged MacOS support, so maybe it could be an option for you now.

But this project is still not production ready and could have memory leakage at least on MacOS.